# texture referenced by sampler cube isnot renderable

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I am trying to create a skybox and for that, I am building a unit cube textured with cube texture.

I have my six images list stored in an array:

```
const cubeImageSources = [
    "grimmnight_bk.jpg",
    "grimmnight_dn.jpg",
    "grimmnight_ft.jpg",
    "grimmnight_lf.jpg",
    "grimmnight_rt.jpg",
    "grimmnight_up.jpg",
];
```

and created cube texture image in webgl:

```
 let indexedImage = new Image();
 indexedImage.crossOrigin = "";

 let cubeMapTexture = gl.createTexture();
 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMapTexture);

for (let i = 0, length = cubeImageSources.length; i < length; i++) {
indexedImage.src = 
       `${window.location.origin}/game/images/texture/${cubeImageSources[i]}`;
indexedImage.onLoad = function(){
           gl.texImage2D(
              gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
              0,
              gl.RGBA,
              gl.RGBA,
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              indexedImage
          );
    }
  }

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

in GLSL fragment shader:-

```
precision highp float;

in vec3 texPosition; 

//texPosition is the position attribute passed from the Vertex Shader

out vec4 outColor;

uniform samplerCube u_SkyTexture;


void main(){

   // outColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   outColor = texture(u_SkyTexture, texPosition);
}
```

samplerCube value is assigned 1 with

```
gl.uniform1i(texIndexLocation, 1);
```

where texIndexLocation is a location of samplerCube in Fragment Shader.

I tried to google but I couldn't find what is the solution of this problem or what is generating this error.

Thank you in advance !!!

[image]

Comment: @rabbid76 thank you for the edit !!! Is it possible for you to guide me where I can look to catch the problem !!!

Comment: Does something change if you set the texture parameters (`gl.texParameteri(...)`) immediately after `gl.bindTexture(...)`?

Comment: no its still same !!!

Comment: Have you checked that all images successfully loaded?